# Does anyone have a better way to do this? Im just learning how to play around with CSS

Tags: html, css

The image is the goal. I need to position each color correctly within the box. It must also be in the center of the browser. The result I got is exactly what the image is just with words. I'm really looking for a better way to do this because I kind of had to guess the left and bottom pixels. I also know it could have been done better and would really love to learn how.

[image]

```css
.border{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  margin:25px 450px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#one {
  background: red;
  height:100px;
}

#two{
 background: yellow;
 height:600px;
 width:100px;
}

#three {
  background: blue;
  height:550px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 600px;
}

#four{
  background: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  width:100px;
  position: relative;
  left:400px;
  bottom: 1150px;
}

#five{
  background: green;
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 1200px;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="border">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div>
    <div id="five">Five</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd opt for using **[percentage-based measurements](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/)**, so that you only need to update the **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** and **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** on `.border` itself. For the `.border`, I've gone with **[`vw` and `vh` units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)** for the `width` and `height` respectively, so that the size of the table adjusts based on the size of the viewport.

Note that you'll also probably want to make use of classes instead of IDs so you can have more than one table. I've used classes in my example, and also replaced the names to make the location identifiers more obvious.

I'd also opt for creating a container for the `#middle` and `#bottom` elements, considering them to be a single 'column'. This way, you can make use of `float` to align the `#left`, `#middle_container` and `#right` columns next to each other, without having to worry about the `width` of `#bottom`.

You can center the entire thing by adding **[`margin: 0 auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** to `.border`, which is shorthand for stating that there shouldn't be any vertical margins, and that the horizontal margins should be automatically calculated (which horizontally centers the element in question).

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.left,
.middle_container,
.right {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}

.middle_container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
}

.middle {
  background: blue;
  height: 80%;
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
  height: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.right {
  background: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="border">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="middle_container">
      <div class="middle">Middle</div>
      <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: ...but the OP also said that it needs to be centered in the browser window?

Comment: @PaulT. - I didn't initially see that, although that's easy enough to implement. I've updated my answer to centralise it as well :)

Comment: Obsidian Age! Wow! I didnt know that I would get help right away. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this and explain it as well.  You also dont need to hope it helps, it does help!:D Thank you again:)

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Obsidian Age's answer, you could also achieve this by using css flexbox.

More info:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

[CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.top {
  background: red;
  height: 20%;
  flex: 100%;
}

.left,
.right,
.middle_container,
.middle {
  height: 80%;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1
}

.middle_container {
  flex: 3;
}

.middle {
  background: blue;
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="middle_container">
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Villekoo! I am reading the additional resources. It is really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To center your art you will need to add position,top,left,margin-top, and margin-bottom. to .border;

```
.border{
      position:fixed; /*or absolute*/
      top:50%; /* add this */
      left:50%; /* add this */
      margin-top:-350px; /*half of your height*/
      margin-left:-250px; /*half of your width*/
      border: 2px solid black;
      width: 500px;
      height: 700px;
      padding: 1px;
}
```

```css
.border{
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-350px;
  margin-left:-250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#one {
  background: red;
  height:100px;
}

#two{
 background: yellow;
 height:600px;
 width:100px;
}

#three {
  background: blue;
  height:550px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 600px;
}

#four{
  background: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  width:100px;
  position: relative;
  left:400px;
  bottom: 1150px;
}

#five{
  background: green;
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 1200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="border">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div>
    <div id="five">Five</div>
   </div>
```